# Openssl bad decryption with symmetric key

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have a problem decrypting a file that I have to encrypt with Openssl ( I use OpenSSL on Windows 10 version 3.1.0 where i encrypt and on Linux version 3.0.2 where i try to decrypt) and I use symmetric key encryption because the file is big and I can not use asymmetric encryption. The commands i use are the following

Command used to generate the symmetric key or password:

`openssl rand -base64 64 > passkey.txt`

Command used to encrypt the file is:

`openssl enc -in file1.xlsx -out file1.enc -e -aes256 -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -kfile passkey.txt`

But when trying to decrypt the file with the following command:

`openssl enc -in file1.enc -out file1.xlsx -d -aes256 -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -k passkey.txt`

I get this error:

> bad decrypt
> 40175D1E257F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:

If i use Openssl to encrypt small files with asymmetric encryption i do not get any errors and everything works fine..
How do I solve this issue? Is there any other way to encrypt big files?

I just found Openssl but i find it pretty hard using it for bigger files.. The approach i have is firstly encrypt the file with the symmetric key or password and than I encrypt the symmetric key with a public key.. Is that a good way to encrypt bigger files?

Comment: Don't you need to use `-kfile` on decryption? Note that transmission errors could also be the cause, remember that ciphertext is binary, not text.

Comment: Can you explain me what do you mean by the binary ciphertext? Thank you.

Comment: It consists of bytes that do not represent characters, and may contain things like line endings and end-of file codes **if** they are treated as such.